# Generate java dump when OutOfMemory

Tags: java, dump

I have a program that should eventually generate `OutOfMemory` .
The program code is:

```
public class VeryLargeObject implements Serializable {
    public static final int SIZE = 1 << 12;

    public String tag;
    public int[][] bigOne = new int[SIZE][SIZE];

    {
        // Initialize bigOne
        for(int i = 0; i < SIZE ; ++i) {
            for(int j = 0; j < SIZE; ++j) {
                bigOne[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
            }
        }
    }

    public VeryLargeObject(String tag) {
        this.tag = tag;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        VeryLargeObject[] vla = new VeryLargeObject[1 << 12];
        for(int i = 0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; ++i) {
            vla[i] = new VeryLargeObject("aa");
        }
    }
}
```

I run the program with the following parameters:

```
java VeryLargeObject -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath="D:\workspace"
```

**The program fails with OutOfMemory but no dump file is generated . Do you have any idea why?**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at VeryLargeObject.<init>(VeryLargeObject.java:14)
        at VeryLargeObject.main(VeryLargeObject.java:32)
```

Comment: Did you mean to say the heap file didnt generate? And shouldn't it be -XX:-HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError instead of -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError (notice the + sign)

Comment: >The program fails with OutOfMemory but now dump if file is generated.  -- Is it a typo? - do you mean **now** or **no**?

Comment: @CoolBeans: The official site: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-VM/html/clopts.html says that the option shoud be with + sign

Comment: @BalabanMario Hi - I am sorry, I am not sure if I follow. So the official docs say the same thing right? "-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError" ? Were you just confirm that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For starter drop the XX options and any options *BEFORE* `VeryLargeObject`, otherwise you pass the parameters to the java program and not the JVM

Comment: i dont find any documentation for VeryLargeObject , can u give us some authentic link.

Comment: @Vipin, 'VeryLargeObject' is the class containing the `main(String[])`. Look at the question, itself.

Comment: i did not notice it , well now i got it :)

Answer (score 20):

The problem is that `-XX:HeapDumpPath` spefies a file and not a path.

```
-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath="c:\temp\dump2.hprof"
```

**added:**

and [bestsss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935520/generate-java-dump-when-outofmemory/4936206#4936206) is right too, so you need to fix both "errors":

```
java -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath="c:\temp\dump2.hprof" VeryLargeObject
```

Comment: '-XX:HeapDumpPath' can also be a path, like this: '-XX:HeapDumpPath=c:/', which will generate dumps with the pattern "java_pid4128.hprof" in the root direcoty of drive C:

Answer (score 5):

I suspect the jvm could not write to the path and fails silently. For example, this has to be a file name in a directory which exists. If you have a directory `D:\workspace` it will fail. If you have `D:\workspace\heap.hprof` it may work. Try creating a blank file of that name first to see you can do this.