# how generating a heap dump automatic in apache tomcat?

Tags: apache, jakarta-ee, tomcat, hprof

I'm having trouble releasing resources in my web application, so I need to know how to configure my tomcat 7.0.41 for generate an .Hprof when will occurrence of a PermGen space.

However I have not found a way to configure it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate java dump when OutOfMemory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935520/generate-java-dump-when-outofmemory)

Answer (score 1):

Following a link that helped me to find and fix a resource / classloader leak in tomcat:

http://frankkieviet.blogspot.ch/2006/10/how-to-fix-dreaded-permgen-space.html