# OutOfMemoryError while reproducing BioGrakn Text Mining example with client Java

Tags: java, stanford-nlp, heap-memory, vaticle-typedb

I'm trying to reproduce the BioGrakn example from the [White Paper "Text Mined Knowledge Graphs"](https://grakn.ai/src/pages/landingpages/downloads/Text-Mining.pdf) with the aim of building a text mined knowledge graph out of my (non-biomedical) document collection later on. Therefore, I buildt a Maven project out of the classes and the data from the textmining use case in the [biograkn repo](https://github.com/graknlabs/biograkn). My pom.xml looks like that:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>TextMining-BioGrakn</groupId>
  <artifactId>TextMining-BioGrakn</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>TextMining-BioGrakn</name>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>repo.grakn.ai</id>
        <url>https://repo.grakn.ai/repository/maven/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>io.grakn.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>api</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.grakn.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>concept</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.graql</groupId>
        <artifactId>lang</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
            <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
            <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.2</version>
            <classifier>models</classifier>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Migrating the schema, inserting the pubmed articles and training the model works perfectly, but then I got an `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded`, which is thrown in the `mineText()` method in the CoreNLP class. This is how the main method in the Migrator class looks like:

```
public class Migrator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        GraknClient graknClient = new GraknClient("localhost:48555");

        GraknClient.Session session = graknClient.session("text_mining");

        try {
            loadSchema("schema/text-mining-schema.gql", session);
            PubmedArticle.migrate(session);
            CoreNLP.migrate(session);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            session.close();
        }

        session.close();
        graknClient.close();
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea on what could cause this error? Am I missing something fundamental here? Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be you need to [allocate more memory for your program](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15523_01/web.1111/e13814/jvm_tuning.htm#PERFM150).

If there is some bug that is causing this issue then [capture a heap dump (hprof) using the HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError flag](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-VM/html/clopts.html). (Make sure you put the command line flags in the right order: [Generate java dump when OutOfMemory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935520/generate-java-dump-when-outofmemory))

Once you have the hprof you can analyze it using [Eclipse Memory Analyzer Tool](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) 
It has a very nice "Leak Suspects Report" you can run at startup that will help you see what is causing the excessive memory usage. Use 'Path to GC root' on any very large objects that look like leaks to see what is keeping them alive on the heap.

If you need a second opinion on what is causing the leak check out the [IBM Heap Analyzer Tool](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/groups/service/html/communityview?communityUuid=4544bafe-c7a2-455f-9d43-eb866ea60091), it works very well also.

Good luck!

Comment: This was a Stanford CoreNLP related issue, see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47974590/stanford-corenlp-exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-h). Setting up the heap space to 4 GB did the trick!